# htImage display and synchronised face capture in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a program for image display and face capture. I am somewhat new to python and OpenCV.

Please find the details below:
I am running Python 2.7.5 on win32 on windows XP
Open cv2 version is 3.0.0

For the program,

Images from a predefined folder needs to be displayed for a fixed time of 500 millisecond in random sequence.

The gap between the images should be covered through a black screen, which should come for any random time gap interval between 1000-1500 millisecond.

Face capture of the viewer needs to be done via webcam once image showed, in between the image show, i.e. at the point of 250 millisecond. The output of the face should be stored in another newly created folder each time the program is run.

I have written the code below, but not getting the sequence right with a synchronised face capture with Haarcascade integration(perhaps required).

I also read somewhere that 'camera index' could be involved in this with possibly the value zero assigned to it. What exactly could be its role?
Please assist in this. Thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Sourceimagepath.jpg', 1)
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("Demo")
cv2.imshow("Demo", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I figured out the solution might lie in pygame.